# Assign and Pin USB device to COM port

Tags: usb

Much like DHCP and LAN IP addresses, I would like to configure a Win10 laptop to reserve and assign a USB device to COM15.  If you have successfully done this before, please state this in your response and any lessons learned.  I look forward to any references / examples.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your device reports a USB serial number in its descriptors, then Windows will remember the device and always assign it to the same COM port number.  You can change the COM port by going to the Device Manager (devmgmt.msc), double-clicking on the COM port, going to the "Port Settings" tab, and clicking "Advanced...".

If your device does not have a serial number in its descriptors, then you need to repeat the procedure above for every USB port on your computer that you might want to plug the device into.  The reason for this is that the device's Device Instance Id, instead of including the serial number, will have some sort of string with ampersands in it that depends on what port the device is plugged into.  This ID is what gets associated with a COM port, so you need to make sure all of the possible IDs of the device are associated with the same COM port.